# Is it possible to add spellchecking for php and javascript comments

Tags: netbeans

I know I can spell check any HTML that appears in PHP documents, but I specifically want to spell check the comments.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [spellchecker module](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/3906/spellchecker). It says on the page that

> This module allows spellchecking of Javadoc comments, Ruby comments, HTML/XML and versioning commit messages.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't check phpdoc comments.